# Changing symfony to specific stable version

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I'm developing an app using symfony syncronized with master branch. Now i want to switch to latest stable release (v2.1.1) using composer. I have the composer.json file with `"symfony/symfony": "2.1.*"`. I change it with `"v2.1.1"` and switch to correct version, but others core bundles still in master branches.

Should I edit manually my composer.lock file with specific versions in v2.1.1 and conserve my own bundles?

Could you describe to me the correct procedure to achieve this?

Comment: why do you want to only use stable versions? Before a request is merged it should pass the created tests, if not it won't be merged. So the code that is in the master branch (dev-master on composer) should always be stable. If not you can help the Symfony community to fill in an issue, or save the issue. Then you can update composer (`composer update`) and you have the best version.

Comment: I meant the latest Symfony Standard Edition version (v2.1.1)

Answer (score 4):

The best way to go is to change versions in `composer.json` file, then run `composer.phar update name-of-package/to-update1 name-of-package/to-update2...` and so forth. That will take care of `composer.lock` in the correct way. This is for packages that are not dependencies of symfony.

If you are only worried about the core symfony dependencies, don't be, they will be updated accordingly to the symfony/symfony package version.

Also, this is a composer question more than a symfony one :) [This is a great presentation by Rafael Dohms about Composer](http://www.slideshare.net/rdohms/composer-putting-dependencies-on-the-score-14144250)

Answer (score 0):

I found this on Symfony cookbook:

**Upgrading Symfony**

Since Symfony is just a group of third-party libraries and third-party libraries are entirely controlled
through composer.json and composer.lock, upgrading Symfony means simply upgrading each of
these files to match their state in the latest Symfony Standard Edition.
Of course, if you've added new entries to composer.json, be sure to replace only the original parts
(i.e. be sure not to also delete any of your custom entries).